# rename files to remove extension on multiple files in linux using a find and exec command

Tags: linux

I have several file that I need to rename. I want to rename to remove the extension on all file (file without extension). I'll prefer a "find and exec" command in Linux but I'm open to other solutions. Thanks

```
 Have
 file.txt
 file1.txt
 file2.txt
 file3.

 Want
 file
 file1
 file2
 file3
```

Comment: Is `file3.` accidental or you want to be able to handle files that has just `.` as extension too?

Comment: I want to be able to handle such file

Comment: See the updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can `rename` command:

```
rename 's/\.[a-z]*$//g' file*
```

If you want to find all files in directory and subdirectories then you can use `find` command:

```
find . -name 'file*' | xargs rename 's/\.[a-z]*$//g'
```

Depending on the files' possible names, you can adjust the regex in the rename command.

---

A bash solution would be:

```
for fname in *.txt; do
   [[ ! -e ${fname} ]] && continue
   new=${fname%.*}
   mv "$fname" "$new"
done
```

The line `[[ ! -e ${fname} ]] && continue` to guard against the scenario when there's file with `.txt` as extension.